# Logging to a file in PostgreSQL windows service

Tags: postgresql, windows, log

I need an alternative for running the following command:

`C:\xxx\pgsql\bin\pg_ctl" -D "C:\xxx\pgsql\data" -l "C:\yyy\log\pgsql.log" start`.

This way the server starts and logs to `C:\yyy\log\pgsql.log`. 
When I try to register the server as a service though - no logging options are available and the server logs to Event Viewer. 
From pg_ctl documentation:

> pg_ctl register [-N servicename] [-U username] [-P password] [-D datadir] [-S a[uto] | d[emand] ] [-w] [-t seconds] [-s] [-o options]

How can I force the server to log into a file? 
Note: I don't want to use one-click installer, I just want to work with unzipped binaries.

Comment: Make sure you enabled the `log_statement` to `log_statement = 'all'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Locate your `postgresql.conf` in the datadir

Find the section that looks like this

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ERROR REPORTING AND LOGGING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Where to Log -

#log_destination = 'stderr'             # Valid values are combinations of
                                        # stderr, csvlog, syslog and eventlog,
                                        # depending on platform.  csvlog
                                        # requires logging_collector to be on.

# This is used when logging to stderr:
#logging_collector = off                # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
                                        # into log files. Required to be on for
                                        # csvlogs.
                                        # (change requires restart)

# These are only used if logging_collector is on:
#log_directory = 'pg_log'               # directory where log files are written,
                                        # can be absolute or relative to PGDATA
#log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'        # log file name pattern,
                                        # can include strftime() escapes
#log_truncate_on_rotation = off         # If on, an existing log file of the
                                        # same name as the new log file will be
                                        # truncated rather than appended to.
                                        # But such truncation only occurs on
                                        # time-driven rotation, not on restarts
                                        # or size-driven rotation.  Default is
                                        # off, meaning append to existing files
                                        # in all cases.
log_rotation_age = 7d                   # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                                        # happen after that time.  0 disables.
#log_rotation_size = 10MB               # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                                        # happen after that much log output.
                                        # 0 disables.
```

simply uncomment and use these parameters. Then, restart the postgres service,

Since you are running postgresql in Windows, it is possible that you may not be allowed to edit `postgresql.conf` while the service is up. If that is the case:

- shutdown the postgres service
- edit `postgresql.conf`
- start the postgres service

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction, Rolando, but your answer just isn't right... As you quote the configuration file, you can only have `stderr, csvlog, syslog, eventlog` there. I had to change the following properties instead: `logging_collector = on, log_directory = ..., log_filename=...`. If you edit your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Hey Vic, thanks. I am a novice at PostgreSQL and provide minor support for it. I am just an old country MySQL DBA.

Comment: log_directory ='C:/Users/Peter/Documents/jonbloe/system/logs' 
worked for me. But don't use the Windows'\' as it works as an escape and the logs end up in a folder PGDATA/UsersPeterDocumentsjonbloesystemlogs